# How to find out if it is Revit viewer which is running or Revit itself Revit api

Tags: c#, api, revit

I am wondering how can find out in my app if the user are using the Revit viewer or running the actual Revit. I am using c#

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
if (args.Contains("/viewer"))
    ...
```

This is how the Revit Viewer shortcut works, and how I most often start Revit through VS, to keep a license free.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to examine the contents of the Revit main window caption and determine whether it contains the words 'viewer':

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/01/determine-revit-demo-mode-revisited.html

Look at the `CmdDemoCheck` external command in [The Building Coder samples](https://github.com/jeremytammik/the_building_coder_samples).

You can also try to modify the current document; if that is possible, it is definitely not in viewer mode:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/03/determine-revit-demo-mode.html

Third and probably best suggestion: check the serial number.  If Revit is running in demo mode, the serial number is 000-00000000:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/01/determine-revit-demo-mode-and-serial-number.html

Comment: Thank you Jeremy this is very helpful. I use the serial-number.